# spacing between font awesome icons

Tags: html, css

I want to erase the annoying spacing between fa icons(with background) in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4wsoqxu/).

I tried margin and word-spacing but it didn't work.

CSS of the icons container :

```
.home-header-sm {
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  word-spacing: 0px;
}

.home-header-sm a,
.home-header-sm a:visited,
.home-header-sm a:hover,
.home-header-sm a:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.fa {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #1D233D;
  width: 30px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: you icons already have spaces between icons what is the problem then??

Comment: If I understand correctly, the spaces must be removed in this instance :)

Comment: Solved: [Plunker](https://jsfiddle.net/2vphgk1n/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues.

1) Your icons have a border around them.  Remove it with:

```
.fa { border: none; }
```

2) Second, remove the whitespace between the tags in the html.

Comment: the whitespace between the tags :'| ...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the border, float the icons to the left, and float the holding container to the right:

https://jsfiddle.net/ww1nescm/1/

```css
.fa {
  border-width: 0;
  float: left;
}

.home-header-sm {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}
```